Не могу понять, почему все три метки Label принимают только последнее значение (2). Подскажите, пожалуйста, мою ошибку
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

C1 = str(5)
C2 = str(10)
C3 = str(2)

nums = (C1, C2, C3)

for x in range(3):
    for y in nums:

        Q1 = y

        L1 = Label(root, text=Q1, width = 20)
        L1.grid(row=x,column=1)

root.mainloop()

При этом, вывел функцией print значение Q1, там все три метки Label отображаются, как надо.

Нашелся ответ:
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

C1 = str(5)
C2 = str(10)
C3 = str(2)

nums = (C1, C2, C3)
number = (1, 2, 3)

for y, x in zip (nums, number):
    
    Q1 = y

    L1 = Label(root, text=Q1, width = 20)
    L1.grid(row=x,column=1)



root.mainloop()


Можно проще, через enumerate: for y, x in enumerate(nums):, нумерация будет с нуля. Если нужно с единицы, то добавляете в enumerate параметр start: enumerate(nums, start=1)
